# vb decompile and retrieving login

Tags: vb6, decompiling

I'm struggling with finding the right login and password for this VB application.....
I already tried : IDA,Olly,vb decompliler (code paste from there) and more... Maybe someone could help me find it or just give me an advice how to.(This is not a commercial app just a exercise I'm unable to complete :(.)

Code decompiled :

```
Private Sub Command1_Click() '402AA0
  var_eax = arg_8.AddRef 'Ignore this
  On Error Resume Next
  var_eax = Form1.Text1 'Ignore this
  var_A4 = Text1.Text
  var_B0 = var_A4
  var_90 = var_A4
  var_eax = Form1.Text2 'Ignore this
  var_A4 = Text2.Text
  var_40 = var_A4
  var_ret_1 = (Len(var_90) = "")
  var_ret_2 = (Len(var_40) = "")
  call Or(var_F8, var_ret_2, var_ret_1, arg_8, arg_8, 00000001h, edi, %ecx = %S_edx_S, arg_8)
  If CBool(Or(var_F8, var_ret_2, var_ret_1, arg_8, arg_8, 00000001h, edi, var_E8 = %S_edx_S, arg_8)) Then
  var_eax = Call Form1.clearoff
  var_B8 = Len(var_90)
  If (var_B8 <> 6) Then
  var_eax = Call Form1.clearoff
  var_50 = vbNullString
  For var_A0 = "" To Len(var_90) - 1 Step 1 
  If var_180 Then
      var_120 = vbNullString
      If (var_50 = vbNullString) Then
        var_E8 = Mid(var_90, CLng(Len(var_90) - var_A0), 1)
       var_A4 = CStr(var_E8)
        var_F0 = Asc(var_A4)
        var_50 = Str(Asc(var_A4))
        call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000003h, 2, var_E8, 2)
        GoTo loc_00403074
     End If
     var_E8 = Mid(var_90, CLng(Len(var_90) - var_A0), 1)
      var_A4 = CStr(var_E8)
      var_F0 = Asc(var_A4)
      var_108 = Str(Asc(var_A4))
      var_118 = var_50 & var_108
     var_50 = var_118
      call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000004h, 2, var_E8, 2, var_108)
      'Referenced from: 00402F7E
    Next var_A0
    GoTo loc_00402E6B
  End If
  var_A0 = Len(var_50)
  var_30 = Str(116)
  call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar(var_180, var_190)
  var_C8 = Str(114)
  var_30 = var_30 + var_C8
  call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, 2, var_C8)
  var_C8 = Str(97)
  var_30 = var_30 + var_C8
  call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, 2, var_C8)
  var_C8 = Str(117)
  var_30 = var_30 + var_C8
  call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, 2, var_C8)
  var_C8 = Str(116)
  var_30 = var_30 + var_C8
  call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, 2, var_C8)
  var_C8 = Str(83)
  var_30 = var_30 + var_C8
  call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, 2, var_C8)
  If (var_50 <> var_30) Then
  var_eax = Call Form1.clearoff
  For var_A0 = 1 To Len(var_90) Step 1
   If var_A0 Then
      var_C8 = Mid(var_90, CLng(var_A0), 1)
      call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, 2, var_C8)
     var_70 = var_70 & Hex(Asc(CStr(var_C8)))
     call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
    Next var_A0
    GoTo loc_0040338A
  End If
  For var_A0 = Len(var_70) To 1 Step -1
   If var_1D0 Then
     var_C8 = Mid(var_70, CLng(var_A0), 1)
      ebx = IsNumeric(var_C8) + 1
      call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, 2, var_C8, var_1A0, var_1B0)
      If IsNumeric(var_C8) + 1 Then
      var_A4 = CStr(Mid(var_70, CLng(var_A0), 1))
      var_130 = Asc(var_A4)
       var_60 = var_60 & Asc(var_A4)
       GoTo loc_0040368C
     End If
      var_C8 = Mid(var_70, CLng(var_A0), 1)
      var_60 = var_60 & var_C8
     'Referenced from: 0040361A
     call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000002h, var_B8, var_C8, 00000002h, var_B8, var_C8)
    Next var_A0
    GoTo loc_004034FB
  End If
 If (var_40 = var_60) Then
    var_120 = "Welcome "
    var_130 = ", Remote access link to Mod-X terminal created"
    call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000005h, var_B8, var_C8, var_D8, var_E8, var_F8, var_1C0, var_1D0)
    GoTo loc_004037D6
  End If
 var_eax = Call Form1.clearoff
 'Referenced from: 004037AB
  End
 var_eax = Call Form1.clearoff
 If Call Form1.clearoff < 0 Then
  Call Form1.clearoff = CheckObj(arg_8, var_00402174, 1784)
 Exit Sub
 GoTo loc_0040386E
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000007, var_B8, var_C8, var_D8, var_E8, var_F8, var_108, var_118, var_004038D8)
 Exit Sub
 'Referenced from: 00403817
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000006, var_180, var_190, var_1A0, var_1B0, var_1C0, var_1D0)
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVar
End Sub
Public Sub clearoff() '403900
 var_eax = arg_8.AddRef 'Ignore this
 var_34 = "Failed"
 var_24 = "Incorrect. Verification failed."
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000004, var_24, var_34, var_44, var_54, 00000008h, %ecx = %S_edx_S, 0000000Ah)
 End
 GoTo loc_004039EC
 call undef 'Ignore this '__vbaFreeVarList(00000004, var_24, var_34, var_44, var_54, var_004039ED)
 Exit Sub
 'Referenced from: 004039CE
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that is pure VB6, please someone with better reverse enginnering knowledges verify it and fix the tag.

Comment: Please try to only add the relevant pieces of code. We don't like to read 1000 lines just to find where your issue is. Also, your issue seems a bit unethical, why do you need the password and login for this application? If it is encrypted you won't be able to find it.

Comment: This is indeed : pure VB6.

Comment: The thing is, the whole code is relevant as the check starts at line 12.I told it in my first post this is an exercise I'm trying to solve for the last 3 days without success. This app doesn't do anything except trowing msg box :var_120 = "Welcome "
  loc_00403725:   var_130 = ", Remote access link to terminal created"

Comment: I don't think that's all the code? Where's `var_180` declared for example? I'd also suggest cleaning the code up as much as possible, like removing all the loc_xxx that aren't used, and I don't think the call undef statements help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, without the program to test it, it appears...

Login: Stuart

Password: 472716574735

The first part merely reverses the input for the login text box and compares it to "trautS" (Ascii chars: 116,114,97,117,116,83), and if it doesn't match, then it clears the form.  So the login must be Stuart.

Password:
var_70 is a hex string of the login

83,116,117,97,114,116 => 537475617274

Then it loops over var_70 in reverse, looking for non-numeric values, which it then grabs a string representation of the number and adds it to the total, otherwise it just puts the number on the final (var_60).

The password appears to just be a hex string of the login name.

Edit: Found a flaw in my logic.

Comment: I tried all possible combinations provided by you but unfortinutelly none of tham works. Here is the link to the app if it helps.... http://www.mediafire.com/download/dq8csp5846vosek/Mod318xxx3Copy1.zip

Comment: Yea, I made an assumption, that was incorrect...I don't do VB anymore.  Updated my answer.